# Images in JS grid won't load fully

Tags: javascript, image, image-gallery, masonry

Wondering if anyone can help. I have a JS image gallery ([link](https://despeaux.consulting/larryhooke/town/project-1/)) where the images won't load fully, unless you resize the browser window. I can't figure out what the problem is. Can you help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Through the usability test, it looks like a images load on scroll down event. Also, you might need to check the `CSS` or if they have used any `CDN` link like bootstrap or MateriazeCss which are having different image display orientation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a little confused though, because when I scroll down the images don't load. Also, on the demo page for this code it loads fine: http://www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/shortcodes/masonry-gallery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.av-masonry {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;//This is causing image to hide
    clear: both; 
}
```

Comment: I love you. Can I send you some beer money?

Comment: @DevendraLattu Thank you!